# Transforming Exponential Decay Function into Linear Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using matplotlib, I have some data that basically comes out looking like this when I have obs at points

```
[.5, .8, .9, .99, .999, .999]
```

[image]

What I'd like in matplotlib is to be able to change the x axis scale so that it looks something like it does in this plot.

[image]

I've looked into changing scale of my x axis, and tried performing log scaling of my x axis, but this did not change anything. I was wondering if there is a way to transform what I have in my first figure into something that has an xaxis similar to what the one in the second figure using matplotlib. Or should I just use a different language like R.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a chunk of code on github that does this

```
class LogitScale(mscale.ScaleBase):
    """
    Scales data in range 0,1 to -infty, +infty
    """

    # The scale class must have a member ``name`` that defines the
    # string used to select the scale.
    name = 'logit'

    def __init__(self, axis, **kwargs):
        """
        Any keyword arguments passed to ``set_xscale`` and
        ``set_yscale`` will be passed along to the scale's
        constructor.
        thresh: The degree above which to crop the data.
        """
        mscale.ScaleBase.__init__(self)
        p_min = kwargs.pop("p_min", 1e-5)
        if not (0 <p_min < 0.5):
            raise ValueError("p_min must be between 0 and 0.5 excluded")
        p_max = kwargs.pop("p_max", 1-p_min)
        if not (0.5 < p_max < 1):
            raise ValueError("p_max must be between 0.5 and 1 excluded")
        self.p_min = p_min
        self.p_max = p_max

    def get_transform(self):
        """
        Override this method to return a new instance that does the
        actual transformation of the data.
        """
        return self.LogitTransform(self.p_min, self.p_max)

    def set_default_locators_and_formatters(self, axis):
        expon_major = np.arange(1, 18)
        # ..., 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.99, ...
        axis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(
                list(1/10.**(expon_major)) + \
                [0.5] + \
                list(1-1/10.**(expon_major))
                ))
        minor_ticks = [0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.7, 0.8]
        for i in range(2,17):
            minor_ticks.extend(1/10.**i * np.arange(2,10))
            minor_ticks.extend(1-1/10.**i * np.arange(2,10))
        axis.set_minor_locator(FixedLocator(minor_ticks))
        axis.set_major_formatter(ProbaFormatter())
        axis.set_minor_formatter(ProbaFormatter())

    def limit_range_for_scale(self, vmin, vmax, minpos):
        return max(vmin, self.p_min), min(vmax, self.p_max)

    class LogitTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
        input_dims = 1
        output_dims = 1
        is_separable = True

        def __init__(self, p_min, p_max):
            mtransforms.Transform.__init__(self)
            self.p_min = p_min
            self.p_max = p_max

        def transform_non_affine(self, a):
            """logit transform (base 10)"""
            p_over = a > self.p_max
            p_under = a < self.p_min
            # saturate extreme values:
            a_sat = np.where(p_over, self.p_max, a)
            a_sat = np.where(p_under, self.p_min, a_sat)
            return np.log10(a_sat / (1-a_sat))

        def inverted(self):
            return LogitScale.InvertedLogitTransform(self.p_min, self.p_max)

    class InvertedLogitTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
        input_dims = 1
        output_dims = 1
        is_separable = True

        def __init__(self, p_min, p_max):
            mtransforms.Transform.__init__(self)
            self.p_min = p_min
            self.p_max = p_max

        def transform_non_affine(self, a):
            """sigmoid transform (base 10)"""
            return 1/(1+10**(-a))

        def inverted(self):
            return LogitScale.LogitTransform(self.p_min, self.p_max)

mscale.register_scale(LogitScale)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    x = np.array([.5, .8, .9, .999, .9999, .99999])
    y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, .1, .01])

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xticks(x)
    plt.gca().set_xscale('logit')
    plt.grid(True)

    plt.show()
```

And my result looks good enough:
[image]

Comment: When replicating someone else's code you should definitely link to it.